# How to pass multiple variables from one model to another model (inner/outer)

Tags: modelica, dymola

Let's say we have the following model:

Collector:

```
model Collector
  Real collect_here;
annotation(defaultComponentPrefixes="inner");
end Collector;
```

and the following model potentially multiple times:

```
model Calculator
  outer Collector collector;
  Real calculatedVariable = 2*time;

equation 
  calculatedVariable = collector.collect_here;

end Calculator;
```

The code above works if calcModel is present only once in the system to be simulated. If the model exists more than once I get a singular system. This is demonstrated by the Example below. Changing the parameter `works` either gives a working or failing system.

```
model Example
  parameter Boolean works = true;

  inner Collector collector;
  Calculator calculator1;
  Calculator calculator2 if not works;

end Example;
```

Using an array inside the collector to pass multiple variables in it doesn't solve it.

Another possible way to solve this is possible by use of connectors, but I only made it work with one calcModel.

Answer (score 4):

Using multiple instances of `Calculator` does brake the model, as the single variable `calculatedVariable` will have multiple equations trying to compute its value. Therefore Dymola complains that the system is structurally singular, in this case meaning that there are more equations than variables in the resulting system of equations.

To give a bit more of an insight: Actually checking `Collector` will fail, as since Modelica 3.0 every component has to be balanced (meaning it has to have as many unknowns as states), which is not the case for `Collector` as it does have one unknown but no equation. This strongly limits the possible applications for the `inner/outer` construct as basically every variable has to be computed where it is defined.

In the given example this is compensated in the overall system if exactly one `Calculator` is used. So this single combination will work. Although this works, it is something that should not be done - for the obvious reason of being very error-prone (and all sub-models should pass the check).

Your question on how to solve this issue actually misses a description of what the issue actually is. There are some cases in my mind that your approach could be useful for:

1. You want to plot multiple variables from a single point, which would be collector. For this purpose "variable selections" should be the most straight-forward way to go: see Dymola Manual Vol. 1, Section "4.3.11 Matching and variable selections" on how to apply them.
2. You want to carry out some mathematical operation on that variables. Then it could be useful to have a vectorized input of variable size. This enables an arbitrary number of connections to this input. For an example of this take a look at: `Modelica.Blocks.Math.MultiSum`
3. You want to route multiple signals between different models (which is unlikely judging from your description, but still): Then `expandable connectors` would be a good possibility. To get an impression of what that does take a look at `Modelica.Blocks.Examples.BusUsage`.

Hope this helps, otherwise please specify more clearly what you actually want to achieve with your code.

Comment: I want to collect the heat loss calculated from a collection of models so that its easier to process in the analysis of the system.

Comment: Do you want a vector of every single heat loss, or is the sum of them enough? For the sum it should be the easiest way to use the components from `Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer` as e.g. in `Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Examples.Motor` where all heat flows are routed to `environment`. By "process in the analysis", do you think of doing this in Modelica of offline after the simulation?

Comment: Although the first step is to add up the heat loss of the individual components, the next step is to add up the sum of other variables such as power. So I need a general applicable solution to the problem. The sum is supposed to be calculated during simulation.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind right now is to use option 2 from my original answer. It is a bit cumbersome as you need to draw a line for each signal, but I can't think of a general way to do it...

Comment: I just tried this and added a connect(variable,multiSum.u[X]) to the models, but the dimension of the input of the multiSum -X- needs to be entered for each of the connect statements. Due to the size of our models, this isn't practicable or rather impossible right now. There is already a solution to my problem inside the TransiEnt library, but I have difficulties understanding it right now. I'll add the solution when I figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

I prepared a demonstrative library for such scenario some days ago. You can access it at https://gist.github.com/beutlich/e630b2bf6cdf3efe96e5e9a637124fe1. If you read the documentation on Example2 you can see the link to [an article from H. Elmqvis et. al.](http://www.ep.liu.se/ecp/118/046/ecp15118427.pdf), which is the clue to your problem. That is, you need a connector, and inherited connects from every Calculator to the one Collector.